# PN code generation

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, continuous-signals

Can we generate PN codes (maximal length sequence) using this technique in Matlab where L is the PN length?

```
pn=2*(rand(1,L)>0.5)-1
```

If yes, why?

Answer (score 3):

No.

This will just create a random sequence of 0 and 1. In order to create a maximum length sequence you need a primitive polynomial as a generator. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_polynomial_(field_theory)